# linking to magento website based on currency

Tags: php, magento, google-ads-api

Basically i need to link to my website, but i need the currency to change based on what link is used.

i need this for google adwords, if i am targeting ireland in adwords, i need my website to display euros. if i am targeting the U.K. i need it to display in Pounds and so on.

the website is developed in magento, and i have a select box at the top of my page that changes the currency throughout the website.

Any ideas how i can do this, the website is [www.funkychristmasjumpers.com](http://www.funkychristmasjumpers.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit per this link on the [Magento forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/60188/#t191078)

You could always add the following bit of code to the top of your /template/directory/currency.phtml file in your theme. I've tested this in a 1.7.0.2 instance and it works nicely.

You just add cy=code to the end of the URL, so for www.funkychristmasjumpers.com it would be http://www.funkychristmasjumpers.com?cy=USD to default to USD. The code applies the currency and then redirects back to the target page

```
$currentCurrency = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

if(!isset($currentCurrency)) $currentCurrency = 'NA';

$currencies = array("GBP","USD","EUR");

if(isset($_GET['cy'])) 
{
    if (in_array(strtoupper($_GET['cy']),$currencies)) {
        if(strtoupper($_GET['cy']) != $currentCurrency)
        {
            header("Location: ".$this->helper('directory/url')->getSwitchCurrencyUrl()."currency/".$_GET['cy']);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```